# How to compare 2 ISODate fields in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, spring-mongo, isodate

I have 2 fields like this in my document

```
"DATE_1" : ISODate("2017-08-11T04:00:00Z")
"DATE_2" : ISODate("2017-06-12T04:00:00Z")
```

I would like to select documents with "DATE_1" is greater than "DATE_2" and i tried the following query which should return the above document.But its not giving any result

```
db.collection.find({"DATE_1":{$gte:"DATE_2"}})
```

How do I compare 2 ISODate fields in Mongo? Also how do I make this query using Spring date mongodb? something like this?

```
Criteria.where("DATE_1").gte("DATE_2");
```

Comment: Nope, you can't make such query. Not in the regular querying language, anyway. Your only hope is `$where` (slow) and, maybe, aggregation pipeline

Answer (score 3):

This should work. Can you please try this and give your feedback.

```
db.getCollection('collectionName').find({$where: function() { 
    return this.DATE_1 > this.DATE_2;
}})
```